# Are sections in openssl config file case sensitive?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I'm reading [this](https://homeworks.it/Html/OpenSSL_PKI_Articolo_Eng.html) and it has the below (excerpt).

```
# Certificate Authority Section
[ ca ]
default_ca              = CA_default                   # The default CA section

# Default CA configuration to sign a Certificate (Public Key)
[ CA_default ]
dir                     = $ENV::CADIR                  # Where everything is kept
certs                   = $dir/certs                   # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir                 = $dir/crl                     # Where the issued CRL are kept
database                = $dir/index.txt               # Database index file

private_key             = $dir/private/root_ca_private_key.pem # The CA Private key
RANDFILE                = $dir/private/.rand           # Private random number file
x509_extensions         = sub_ca_cert                  # The extentions to add to the 
                                                       # certificate (Public Key)
name_opt                = ca_default                   # Subject Name options
cert_opt                = ca_default                   # Certificate field options
crl_extensions          = crl_ext                      # Certificate Revocation List (CRL) exstensions
default_days            = 2920                         # How long to certify for (8 years)
```

At the line below, is the `ca_default` the same as `CA_default` above?

```
name_opt                = ca_default                   # Subject Name options
```

Comment: **NO.** The value of `[ca]default_CA` is a section name; you can use any name you want as long as the item and the section match. The values of `[?]name_opt,cert_opt` are not section names, they are [strings like those passed to `-nameopt` and `-certopt` in `x509`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-ca.html#name_opt-cert_opt) and only the values defined by the code can be used. This is more like `copy_extensions`: the value of that can be `none` or `copy` or `copyall`, but it can't be `purple` because there is no feature to copy (or even identify) purple extensions.